# ARKit How to draw plane from corners not from center

Tags: ios, swift, math, scenekit, arkit

I have vertical  Plane let's say wall. In wall I have to add another Plane from point1 to point2 where point1 and point2 are SCNVector of hit test from Wall.

Wall node is rotated Euler angle Y with dynamic value. to draw Plane on wall I have to apply

```
 plane.eulerAngles = wall.eulerAngles
```

it is working fine. I am able to draw plane. **but plane is drawn from centre**  which I don't want. I want plane to be drawn from top corner so I have to minus  width /2 and height /2 from point1.

But Plane is rotated so by changing x , y Value will not work here. I have also need to change Z value according to Y rotation

Question : How to calculate width /2 and height /2 in rotated plane ?

How to reproduce

1) Create Xcode project with ARKit application

2) in ship.scn file add SCNPlane object

3) in right panel change angle of Y to 30

4) Move the plane with RED arrow only observe that with X value there is also Z value changed

[image]

after move with red arrow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the inspector you can set the "Editing space" to "World" (instead of "Local") and when using the manipulator (arrows in the viewport) you also have an option to change the editing space to "world" or "parent" so that your changes don't take the node's rotation into account.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply . Actually question is that how to find shown value programatically. Like Image 1 has xyz is 5,5,5 but after I move X,Z value changed because of rotation 30 . SO I want to find the corner position similarly. Sorry for my confusing question !!